# Elementary 5.1 Hera. Unable to login with standard user account

Tags: greeter, release-hera

After I created a standard user account, unable to login with that user account.

My Admin account has no problem logging in.

any suggestion?

thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to change the password of the user, may be, by mistake, you have entered the password and press a key that was not the same even during the confirmation

Comment: no, I made sure I entered the password correctly. Howeve,r, it suddenly is working now. No idea why. Thank you anyway for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> Look I don't have enough reputation to comment, I'll remove this clarification once it's clear... (please don't downvote)
>
> - Is your login showing "incorrect password" or just loops back to login screen in the (no message)?
> - What is the details about graphics & corresponding drivers?
>
> Tip: Include system info (not personal data) while asking a question. Install [neofetch](https://github.com/dylanaraps/neofetch) for crisp output: `sudo apt install neofetch`

If the login screen just loops back without any message please follow the steps below:

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and login into the shell.

Now run `ls -lA | grep 'Xauth*'`. you'll see the line

```
-rw-------  1 root root   53 Nov 29 10:19 .Xauthority
```

then you need to do `chown username:username .Xauthority` and try logging in (you may also need to do the same for for `.ICEauthority`).

Else, do `ls -ld /tmp`. Check for the first 10 letters in the left: they should read exactly so: `drwxrwxrwt`.

```
drwxrwxrwt 15 root root 4096 Nov 30 04:17 /tmp
```

Else, you need to do `sudo chmod a+wt /tmp` and check again.

Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to reach the login screen again, and restart.